# Undefined Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

i am trying to make a for loop out of a var variable but it doesn't work. For some reason tempArray.length is always undefined, it never return anything different. Can anyone help ?

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    tempArray = arr[i];

    for (k = 0; k <= tempArray.length; i++) {
        if (tempArray[k] != /[0-9]+/) {
            countinue;
        }
```

Comment: First, that code is incomplete. Second, you must make sure that `arr` contains arrays (or objects with the length property).

Answer (score 0):

```
var tempArray = [];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    tempArray = arr[i];
}
for (k = 0; k <= tempArray.length; i++) {
    if (tempArray[k] != /[0-9]+/) {
        countinue;
    }
}
```

Temp array needs to be set to an array.
Loop through and build tempArray first, then loop through the temp array and do what ever you need to.